# Problemas con "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

he estado buscando es diferentes sitios sobre como resolver este error. Ya se que hay muchas preguntas sobre esto en este foro, pero ninguna me funciona o sus respuestas no están completas.

**Esto es toda la parte de JS que esta en mi archivo html:**

```
<script>
    const url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=termodin%C3%A1mica";

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { //Data es el resultado de "response.json()"
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
</script>
```

**Mensaje de error:**

Access to fetch at 'https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=termodin%C3%A1mica' from origin 'http://000.000.0.00' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled...

Si cambio el link de Wikipedia por otro como... https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ funciona correctamente.

Lo estoy cargando en un servidor local en XAMPP.

Gracias por su ayuda!!!

---

Ese codigo que mandaron no me funciona, no se si no se aplica a lo que necesito. Pero si no es mucha molestia... Alguien podria pasarme un codigo que funcione con esta URL (https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=termodin%C3%A1mica)?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

en el fetch, debes incluir la llamada como CORS:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3977/api/' + payload,
            params = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({ 'name': name, etc etc etc}),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            };

        var request = new Request(url, params);
        var resp_aux

        fetch(request)
```

Comment: No voy a comentar nada malo de tu respuesta, puesto que ese puede ser precisamente el problema, en vez de ello añadire informacion importante que el usuario debe tener en cuenta, y es que debe asegurarse de leer sobre las *CORS*, porque pese a que tu envies desde el frontend con mode especificado como `CORS`, esto no significa que el backend te vaya dar acceso, por ejemplo una `API` privada requerira de una `API KEY` para poder acceder a sus funcionalidades, si no posees esa `API KEY` o si la `API` NO es publica, simplemente no te molestes, no vas a lograr usar la `API`.

Comment: por lo tanto el `OP` debera consultar si la `API` de `wikipedia` es abierta al publico o si requerira de una `API KEY` o un `token` para poder acceder a sus datos y funcionalidad.